# How to resolve the domain server name from .NET

Tags: vb.net

Hi
In a single server Windows domain, does anyone know how to get the servername.
For example, in my test environment, we have a single Windows Small Business Server 2008 called horatio, it is the domain controller for longtest.local.

I have played around with the system.dns (with no positive results) :

```
    Dim myIP As IPHostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(My.Computer.Name)
    Dim IPAddress As String = myIP.AddressList.GetValue(0).ToString
    Dim myFullDomainName = Dns.GetHostEntry(IPAddress).HostName
    Dim DomainParts() As String = myFullDomainName.Split("."c)
    Dim DomainName As String = DomainParts(1)
```

However, I cannot seem to grab the servername, I need a function like :

GetDomainServer() that will return horatio (from the example above.
Driving me a bit mad this one.

Regards
Mark Harby
Nottingham. UK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an environment variable called LOGONSERVER that you can use:

```
var domainServerName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LOGONSERVER");
```

Comment: Brilliant, there's always a simple way. Thanks Klaus

Answer (score 0):

Ask the server. Like environment variable. The local machine name is available in one environment variable.

Comment: TomTom, how does that help when I am trying to resolve the server name from a domain client ?